# How can i take the values from a column and insert them as a new row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe which looks like this:

```
    Item_ID  User_ID  Value  Residents  Above_18
       0        1      0        5.0       2.0
       0        2      0        4.0       2.0
       0        3      0        2.0       2.0
```

I would like to take the value from residents column and fill it in value and fill 1 as item ID
and have another row with same User_ID and item_ID as 2 and value from above_18

The dataframe should look like this

```
    Item_ID  User_ID  Value  
       1        1      5         
       2        1      2    
       1        2      4     
       2        2      2  
       1        3      2       
       2        3      2
```

Comment: This is a `pandas` question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Seems like a job for `pd.melt`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can solve your problem by building each of the two result rows using [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) and then merging them together.

It might not be the most efficient but would look like the following

```
table = [
    [0, 1, 0, 5.0, 2.0],
    [0, 2, 0, 4.0, 2.0],
    [0, 3, 0, 2.0, 2.0]
]

row1 = [[1, i[1], i[3]] for i in table]
row2 = [[2, i[1], i[4]] for i in table]
result = row1 + row2

# [
#    [1, 1, 5.0],
#    [1, 2, 4.0],
#    [1, 3, 2.0],
#    [2, 1, 2.0],
#    [2, 2, 2.0],
#    [2, 3, 2.0]
# ]
```